# integral of monotonic increasing function

Tags: integration, analysis, limits, fourier-series, monotone-functions

I have to show that if we have a monotonic increasing function $ g :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)=0$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^1\frac {g(x) \sin (nx)}{x}dx=0$$
Because of the limit of $g(x)$ as $x$ goes to $0$, it implies that $\forall\varepsilon\gt0$, $\exists \delta\gt 0$ , $0\le g(x)\lt\varepsilon$, if $0\lt x\lt\delta$. We can now split the integral in two parts: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^1\frac {g(x) \sin (nx)}{x}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^\delta\frac {g(x) \sin (nx)}{x}dx+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\delta}^1\frac {g(x) \sin (nx)}{x}dx=$$$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^\delta\frac {g(x) \sin (nx)}{x}dx$$ The second part vanishes as n goes to infinity because of the Riemann lemma.
So, my problem is to evaluate the first part.

Comment: I think this is related to [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions)... but need to have a closer look at it.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net In this case, $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{x}$ is not necessarily absolutely integrable.

Comment: @MarkViola I know. I was more looking at writing $\frac{\sin nx}{x} =(\frac{1}{x}- \frac{1}{\sin x})\sin nx + \frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}$ to use Dirichlet kernel property with $g$. And the first part of RHS of the equality is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

From Bonnet's Mean Value Theorem, since $g(x)$ is monotonic and $\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}$ is integrable, there exists a number $\xi\in(0,\delta)$ such that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\delta \frac{g(x)}{x}\sin(nx)\,dx&= g(0^+)\int_0^\xi \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\,dx+g(\delta)\int_\xi^\delta \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=g(\delta)\int_{n\xi}^{n\delta}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx
\end{align}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, I can finish from there, but I have never seen this theorem so I'm still looking for another way to prove it !

Comment: You have never seen the second mean value theorem?

Comment: Yes, sorry I haven't seen it. For information this problem I posed came from our course on Fourier Series and not from pure analysis :)

Comment: The MVT is usually taught in calculus.  If you're studying Fourier Series, then one prerequisite is surely calculus.  And you're using the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: Hi Tonio.  Would you please let me know how I can improve my answer?  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If this was not useful, I am happy to delete it.  Looking forward to your reply.  Thank you in advance.